# How to use Azure-Python SDK `ResourcesMoveInfo` class in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I came across this python class `ResourcesMoveInfo` for moving resources(Azure Images) from one subscription to another with Azure python SDK.

But it's failing when I use it like below:

> Pattern 1

reference from https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/azure-sdk-for-python/v1.0.3/azure-sdk-for-python.pdf

**Usage:**

```
metadata = azure.mgmt.resource.resourcemanagement.ResourcesMoveInfo(resources=rid,target_resource_group='/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}'.format(self.prod_subscription_id,self.resource_group))
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: module 'azure.mgmt.resource' has no attribute 'resourcemanagement'
```

> Pattern 2

reference from - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2019_07_01.models.resourcesmoveinfo?view=azure-python

**Usage:**

```
metadata = azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_06_01.models.ResourcesMoveInfo(resources=rid,target_resource_group='/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}'.format(self.prod_subscription_id,self.resource_group))
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: module 'azure.mgmt.resource.resources' has no attribute 'v2020_06_01'
```

Any help on this requirement/issue would be helpful. Thanks!

Adding code snippet here:

```
import sys
import os
import time

from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
import azure.mgmt.resource
#from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_06_01.models import ResourcesMoveInfo
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from cred_wrapper import CredentialWrapper


class Move():
    def __init__(self):

        self.nonprod_subscription_id = "abc"
        self.prod_subscription_id = "def"
        self.credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id= os.environ["ARM_CLIENT_ID"],
            client_secret= os.environ["ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"],
            tenant_id= os.environ["ARM_TENANT_ID"]
            )
        #resource client for nonprod
        self.sp = CredentialWrapper(self.credential)
        self.resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(self.sp,self.nonprod_subscription_id)
        self.resource_group = "imgs-rg"


    def getresourceids(self):
        resource_ids = list(resource.id for resource in self.resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group("{0}".format(self.resource_group)) if resource.id.find("latest")>=0)
        return resource_ids

    def getresourcenames(self):
        resource_names = list(resource.name for resource in self.resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group("{0}".format(self.resource_group)) if resource.id.find("latest")>=0)
        return resource_names

    def deleteoldimages(self,name):
        #resource client id for prod
        rc = ResourceManagementClient(self.sp,self.prod_subscription_id)
        for resource in rc.resources.list_by_resource_group("{0}".format(self.resource_group)):
            if resource.name == name:
                #2019-12-01 is the latest api_version supported for deleting the resource type "image"
                rc.resources.begin_delete_by_id(resource.id,"2020-06-01")
                print("deleted {0}".format(resource.name))

    def moveimages(self):
        rnames = self.getresourcenames()
        for rname in rnames:
            print(rname)
            #self.deleteoldimages(rname)
        time.sleep(10)
        rids = self.getresourceids()
        rid = list(rids[0:])
        print(rid)
        metadata = azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_06_01.models.ResourcesMoveInfo(resources=rid,target_resource_group='/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}'.format(self.prod_subscription_id,self.resource_group))
        #moving resources in the rid from nonprod subscription to prod subscription under the resource group avrc-imgs-rg
        if rid != []:
            print("moving {0}".format(rid))
            print(self.resource_client.resources.move_resources(source_resource_group_name="{0}".format(self.resource_group),parameters=metadata))
            #self.resource_client.resources.move_resources(source_resource_group_name="{0}".format(self.resource_group),resources=rid,target_resource_group='/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}'.format(self.prod_subscription_id,self.resource_group))
            #self.resource_client.resources.begin_move_resources(source_resource_group_name="{0}".format(self.resource_group),parameters=metadata)
            



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Move().moveimages()
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error-trace to check the path of error message occuring.

Answer (score 0):

From your inputs we can see that the code looks fine. From your error messages, the problem is with importing the modules.

Basically when we import a module few submodules will get installed along with and few will not. This will depend on the version of the package, to understand which modules are involved in a specific version we need to check for version-releases in official documentation.

In your case, looks like some resource modules were missing, if you could see the entire error-trace, there will be a path with sitepackages in our local. Try to find that package and its subfolder(Modules) and compare them with Azure SDK for Python under Resource module, you can find this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/resources/azure-mgmt-resource/azure/mgmt/resource/resources).

In such situation we need to explicitly add those sub modules under our package. In your case you can simple download the packaged code from Git link which I gave and can merge in your local folder.